# The "How to Ask" Page Should Explicitly Mention That You Need To Actually Ask a Question

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Every day I run into posts that do not state a question, not in the title and not in the body. The user makes a bunch of statements then clicks the "Post your Question" button despite them not actually asking a question. This leaves it up to the users to decipher intent from the asker's statements and ends up causing comment spam to firstly figure out what the question even is, then more comments to finally pursue information on the actual question once it has been figured out.

I might prefer a sledgehammer where you aren't even allowed to click the "Post your Question" button until the site detects a `?` character, but barring that, I think the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, which is linked directly on the "[Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)" page under "asking help", should have a section for "Make sure you ask a question", where the body says something like, "Do not just string together a bunch of statements, be sure to clearly and concisely state your actual question either in the post title or in the post body. Posts without a clearly stated question are lower quality, tend to garner downvotes, and will reduce your chances of getting a useful answer", or something similar.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. If somebody posts a question that doesn't actually ask a question, the odds are vanishingly small that they'd read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the first place.
2. How to Ask already includes a section on proof-reading to make sure your question makes sense. If that isn't enough, then explicitly telling people to ask a question isn't going to make much difference.

If someone creates a post without asking a question, it's best to just vote to close as "Unclear what you're asking" and move on. Asking clarifying questions and making edits is nice, but don't feel obliged if you don't feel that the "question" can be salvaged.

Comment: 3. Sometimes a "question" can be perfectly clear and answerable without a _grammatical_ question in it. (Yeah, probably not often, but it can and does happen occasionally.)

Comment: @Kendra This is true. In fact, if I just scroll back to the top of this page...

Comment: 0. The button people click on says "Ask Question" and the resulting page has the title "Ask a Question" and mentions "questions" in the sidebar several times; how more obvious can it be that you need to ask a question?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker wait... so that means that the Q in... "Q&A" site is.... OOOOOOOOOH! Now I get it!