# Propose a mandatory Question Field to be filled before submitting a Question

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions

Often questions get posted which only include statements or maybe imply what the OPs problem or request is, but throughout the problem statement the user either does not specifically ask a direct question or leaves it to the reader to determine what the concise question is (the user either omitted using a question mark '?' in their question, or expected their problem statement offered enough information for the user to determine what the question may be).

When questions get submitted and *do not* including a specific question, often readers immediately comment something similar to "What is your ***specific*** question?" or "You forgot to actually ***ask*** a question!"

Would it be reasonable to include a separate field in the question form, which is mandatory for the poster to fill in with a specific question that would summarize their problem **?**

Something similar to the format of the above paragraph. Possibly a form that would autofill a question mark '?' at the end of the form that indicates it should satisfy the question that is often expected by readers, potentially making the question and answer process more efficient, or reducing the number of questions that get flagged as "Unclear" what the OP is asking.

Hopefully this question has already been answered and can be flagged as such, yet I could not find a duplicate.

Comment: This shouldn't be mandatory for everyone, as according to a guess off the top of my head more than 20% of askers actually ask a question. Perhaps it can be a great feature if it's triggered only by certain heuristics.

Comment: This question is highly unpopular, leave it or delete it?

Comment: @downshift You couldn't delete it even if you wanted to.

Comment: [Answer to a related (but not quite duplicate) question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338120/2607247) I would also read the comments under that answer.

Comment: @Servy, so the delete button is fake? Then what's the point of downvoting.

Comment: @Kendra, thank you for linking that related question, that answer and its comments were satisfactory enough to simply mark my question as a dupe and close.

Comment: @downshift The author cannot delete their question with an upvoted answer.  You could have deleted the question before the answer you got was upvoted (or posted in the first place).  Mods or users with 10k rep could vote to delete it with the answers (so the button would still be useful for them).

Comment: Thanks for that info @Servy, why then does the delete button still give me an option to confirm to the prompt "We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.
Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?", which suggests to me that it is deceivingly possible.

Comment: @downshift Because the check of whether or not you're allowed to delete it is done after  you try to delete it, not before.

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks for clarifying ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're probably overestimating the number of questions that are closed as "unclear what you're asking". It's not exactly a problem in dire need of addressing.

You're also assuming that users would **always put a *question* in this field.** Help vampires would just enter garbage into it, just like how they add garbage text to questions that are blocked because they dumped 3GB of code.

It wouldn't really help streamline the answering process, either, because the reason most people don't answer a question that they see is because they're not interested in answering, don't have time, or just don't *have* an answer.

Comment: "just like how they add garbage text to questions that are blocked because they dumped 3GB of code." That just gave me an idea. What if we blocked questions where a gigantic code block is followed by gibberish, "some details some details some details" or a variation of it?

Comment: Not to mention that forcing a question on a post gives NO guarantee it'll be clear....

Comment: @dorukayhan How exactly would we detect that?